# Is it grammatically correct to say "2 sweet wrappers"?

Tags: word-usage

I am trying to describe this image.

[image]

> there are two sweet wrappers and one piece of candy.

Is it grammatically correct to say "2 sweet wrappers"?

I googled "2 sweet wrappers" and most hits are about candy bags rather than sweet wrappers, which seem to indicate the expression is incorrect.

I don't even know the right/appropriate keywords I could use to perform a search.

Could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

---

The image and sentences is adapted from [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wrapper), so I am pretty sure the phrase "a sweet wrapper" is grammatically correct.

Comment: Why would it not be correct? If you can name an object, you can say that there are two (or any number) of them.

Comment: ...but _sweet_ is British English and _piece of candy_ American!